# Cashier Scanning Algorithm Problem

Tags: algorithms

I came across a problem about a cashier scanning goods that I'm stuck on. I paraphrase the question below.

> A cashier only has `x` time to scan a person's goods. The goods come 1
> item per time step in a conveyor belt. In one time step, the cashier
> can either scan an item or bag the item (so when bagging, the cashier
> misses the item on the conveyor belt for that time step). The place to
> hold scanned, unbagged goods has a max capacity of `c`, where each
> good takes 1 unit space. However, once the cashier starts to bag
> scanned items, the cashier must bag all unbagged scanned items. The
> cashier also wants to ensure he makes the most money possible. How
> would the cashier go about choosing the goods such that he maximizes
> the amount of money the buyer spends. What is the maximum amount of
> money the cashier can make?

This seems to be a modification of the 0-1 knapsack problem, where the max capacity `c` is the max capacity of the knapsack, the price of the item is its value in the knapsack, and all items have a 1 unit space. I am, however, confused about how I would incorporate the "conveyor belt" of missing items and the moving of items out of `c` into the algorithm. I imagine this could still be run in $O(nc)$ time with $O(c)$ space complexity (in fact the original problem statement says it should be possible in these bounds). How would I go about modifying the 0-1 knapsack problem for this?

Comment: Please credit the original source of this task.

Comment: @D.W. - a random paper I found at the university library (with some notes a la knapsack) but that seems so random people will unnecessarily start doubting it in the comments

Comment: @ztn78420eoopy This random paper probably has a title and authors you can cite, no? Or do you mean literally a piece of paper?

Comment: @orlp - no literally a random piece of paper with this scribbled on that I happened to see and it is now taking up way too much of my time

Answer (score 1):

Let the $i$th item have profit $p_i$, and assume there are $n$ items passing by.

We can construct a graph where the nodes are pairs $(k, b)$ where $k$ is the number of timesteps, and $b$ is the number of items in our bagging area. We have $0 \leq k \leq x$ and $0 \leq b \leq c$.

Then, avoiding invalid nodes and/or nonsensical self-edges,

1. Add edges from $(i-1, b)$ to $(i, b + 1)$ with weight $-p_i$. These represent scanning an item.
2. Add edges from $(i, b)$ to $(i + 1, b)$ with weight $0$ for all $i$. These represent skipping an item.
3. Add edges from $(i, b)$ to $(i + b, 0)$. These represent bagging all scanned items.

Now we have a directed weighted acyclic graph, in which we can find the longest path in linear time. And the longest path between $(0, 0)$ and $(x, 0)$ precisely gives us the maximum profit (and following the path also gives us the steps used).

There are $O(cn)$ edges, and thus that is our complexity.

Comment: right but this would take more than the $O(c)$ space that the knapsack problem modification would, no?